# Another " would" usage to maintain the same tense in the sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Touché on  modify the joke to serve your best interest, **although it'd probably lose its luster as you'd be disregarding traditionally Jewish stereotypes.**

Is this sentence grammatically correct? Please elaborate.

Comment: Your question as it stands is off topic.  Is there a particular part of the quote with which you are struggling?  What do you think might be wrong?

Comment: I hate to be a bother, but this question is very unclear. What is exactly your problem? Explain your problem, your doubts and your needs in depth. EDIT: Oh Snumpy beat me to it :)

Comment: Is this sentence correct as it's written? My concern is with "although" clause

Comment: Can you clarify how the title relates to the body of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Touché on **modifying** the joke to serve
>   your best interest, although it'd
>   probably lose its luster as you'd be
>   disregarding **traditional** Jewish
>   stereotypes.

This should be the corrected version, imo.

**EDIT** to answer further questions as asked in the comments:

1. <strike>Why comma?</strike> Well, you cannot have *touché on modify a joke*, that doesn't work at all. You need to start with *touché on modifying a joke*, <strike>but still, I think connecting them with a comma is a lot more dramatic, simpler and easier to understand.</strike>
2. Why traditional? Well, because it's **traditional stereotypes**, not *traditionally stereotypes*, that doesn't work at all. It could be **traditionally good stereotypes**, but certainly **not** *traditionally Jewish stereotypes*.

Comment: Ooh, good catch on the *traditional* — I missed that in my answer!

Comment: why traditional? why comma?

Comment: I think that original quotation would stand if you added quotes: `Touche' on "modifying the joke to serve your best interest", although ... traditional Jewish stereotypes`.  The quotes because they would reference the phrase that 'hit', but *traditional Jewish stereotypes* because they are traditional stereotypes of Jewish people, not stereotypes that are held by Jewish people traditionally. (If I interpret the sentence correctly.)

Comment: I don't think your version is grammatically correct. The *modifying* clause lacks a finite verb.

Comment: Uhm, what? I believe it's perfectly correct. I've heard a similar phrase a million times before, like *Great job modifying the code! It finally works!*

Comment: @RiMMER: That is different. The phrase *great job* can stand on its own as a main clause, because the reader easily supplies *[you've done a] great job modifying the code*. Not so with *touché* followed by a comma: 1. *touché* requires *on* to carry a clause on its own if this clause is supposed to consist of more than just the interjection *touché*, as shown in PLL's answer; 2. the comma separates *touché* from the rest, forcing the *modifying* part to be taken as a second main clause, which would require some verb or phrase that can carry a main clause.

Comment: Okey then, edit my answer to fix it, please.

Comment: @RiMMER: OK, edited and up-voted!

Answer (score 1):

One simple error: it should begin

> Touché on modifying the joke…

since *on* here needs to be followed by a noun phrase, and so the verb *modify* must be used in its gerund form *modifying*.

More debatably, I would suggest using simple past tense rather than conditional forms:

> …it probably loses some luster, since you’re disregarding…

since the beginning suggests that someone has already modified the joke.  *It’d probably lose* and *you’d be disregarding* are more natural if the modification is still hypothetical, in a context like:

> Don’t modify the joke; it’d probably lose some luster…

So depending on context — is the modification definitely made, or still somewhat in question? — the simple past forms might be more appropriate, or the original conditional forms.

**Edit:** as Rimmer’s answer points out, it should also be *traditional Jewish stereotypes*, not *traditionally*, since *traditional* here is describing the stereotypes themselves, not the sense in which they’re Jewish.

Comment: +1. I think *traditionally* is still possible; a somewhat awkward example: *How is this stereotype Jewish? The word "glitch" is hardly felt to be Jewish any more. — Saying "glitch" all the time is traditionally a Jewish stereotype, though I suppose it is now quite current among goyim as well.* But I agree that *traditional Jewish joke* is probably much better here.

Comment: @Cerberus: completely agreed.  I only meant to suggest that in this context it should probably be *traditional*, not that *traditionally* is grammatically wrong.

Comment: Agreed! In retrospect your edit seems quite clear; I'm not sure why I didn't leave it at that. // Funny, somehow *traditionally* sounded quite natural to my ears as well: it was only when I thought about it that I agreed it was an inferior choice. Probably something with word-class patterns.